# request focus must be called error android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I was planning to change from one page to another so the first screen has title bar and navigation bar on it and I want to change to another page with just textview on it with no title bar when I am out of fucos to my edittext.

Here is the Code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity{
     private EditText edittext;
     private ListView list;
     private CustomListAdapter customAdapter;
     private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
     private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // this.tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        //new ConnnectionRequest(tv,"95","3025");
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle("Rodolfo");
                edittext.setText("");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle("Navalon");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        addKeyListener(); 


        }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
          return true;
        }
        // Handle your other action bar items...

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void addKeyListener() {
        List<String> arrayStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayStrings.add("rodolfo");
        arrayStrings.add("erodolfo2");

        edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
        edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    //Remove title bar
                    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                    //Remove notification bar
                    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);



                    setContentView(R.layout.second_screen);

                }
            }
        });

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        customAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.product_name,arrayStrings);
        list.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                MainActivity.this.customAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

            }

        });
    }  
}
```

At my addkeyListener method where my edditext is been initialized also in the setOnFucos change where my changing to page occur and got error. I dont know why its giving me an error.

```
10-03 20:47:47.916: E/AndroidRuntime(9023): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 20:47:47.916: E/AndroidRuntime(9023): **android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content**
10-03 20:47:47.916: E/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:268)
10-03 20:47:47.916: E/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:3310)
10-03 20:47:47.916: E/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at com.example.octranspodestination.MainActivity$2.onFocusChange(MainActivity.java:122)
10-03 20:47:47.916: E/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at android.view.View.onFocusChanged(View.java:4571)
10-03 20:47:47.916: E/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged(TextView.java:7640)
10-03 20:47:47.916: E/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at android.widget.EditText.onFocusChanged(EditText.java:172)
10-03 20:47:47.916: E/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at android.view.View.clearFocus(View.java:4461)
10-03 20:47:47.916: E/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at android.view.ViewGroup.clearFocus(ViewGroup.java:775)
10-03 20:47:47.916: E/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:8518)
10-03 20:47:47.916: E/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:5631)
10-03 20:47:47.916: E/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$ViewDragCallback.onViewPositionChanged(DrawerLayout.java:1364)
10-03 20:47:47.916: E/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper.continueSettling(ViewDragHelper.java:730)
10-03 20:47:47.916: E/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.computeScroll(DrawerLayout.java:764)
10-03 20:47:47.916: E/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12594)
10-03 20:47:47.916: E/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12650)
```

Comment: What error? Could you post logs?

Comment: What's line 46 of your code?

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace says

> requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Looking at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#requestFeature%28int%29), this is true:

> Enable extended screen features. This must be called before
>   setContentView(). May be called as many times as desired as long as it
>   is before setContentView().

In `onCreate()`, you *already* call `setContentView()` so when your editText changes focus and calls `requestFeature` again(), an Exception is thrown.

Since it is usually bad practice to swap content Views in one Activity. You probably should rethink about your app design - usually getting a user's input should not cause the status bar and title to disappear. You could launch a new Activity or make a Dialog instead, but this depends on your needs.

Comment: So I need to create a new activity and swap it through Intent class? Am I right

Comment: @user2844805 If you require that when the user input whatever they need in the `EditText`, the title and status bar disappear, then something like that should work - use [`startActivityForResult()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868994/can-anybody-tell-what-is-use-of-start-activity-for-result-in-android).